# Making notification in android not collapse

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I wanted a notification which always stays in expanded mode and doesn't collapse when user tries to do it.

I tried setting : 
`setCustomContentView(null)` and even not calling the former function.
I also tried all possible plays with other methods of `NotificationBuilder` but to no avail!

Can somebody suggest how to achieve the above? The reverse is quite easy to do but this would require some hack imo!

Answer (score 0):

An expandable Notification is a special case of a Notification [Big View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify). If the Big View is not at the top of the notification drawer, it it shown 'closed' and is expandable by swipe. Quote from Android Developers:

> A notification's big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture. Expanded notifications are available starting with Android 4.1.

```
String  someLongText="here is your long text",channelId="default"; 
Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Exemplo 1")
            .setChannelId (channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(icon1).setContentText("Hello World!");

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigText.bigText(someLongText);
    bigText.setBigContentTitle("Hello world title");
    bigText.setSummaryText("Hello world summary");
    mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);
    mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back
    // stack for
    // the
    // started Activity.
    // getApplicationContext() ensures that navigating backward from
    // the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
            .create(getApplicationContext());

    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent
    // itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the
    // stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I am asking the reverse! This is obvious